# How can I trim around an electrical outlet?

Tags: electrical, trim, baseboard

I had the floor in a sunroom raised up to be level with the floor in the rest of the house. The electrical was already in place, and I didn't think to check how the new floor height would affect the trim. Now I'm left with an outlet that is 1 1/2" into the baseboards:

[image: baseboard]
(Please ignore the almond colored outlet, leaving those in place until everything is painted)

My first thought was to just notch the baseboard like you see in the photo, but I was wondering if there is a better way. What would you do in this situation?

EDIT:
I just cut this out of some scrap I have. Does the angle make it look better or worse?
[image: angled]

EDIT #2:
A twitter follower suggested I carry the bevel around like this (ignored the botched bottom piece). I think this might be the winner.
[image: beveled]

Comment: I like the angled... Just paint it.

Comment: Looks pretty good angled. If you're comfortable with the electrical work, though, it's probably about the same amount of work to simply remove the box (probably involves destroying it) and reinstalling a bit higher. This assumes you have slack in the cable too, so your approach is safer.

Comment: I would love to move it up, but no slack in the cable.

Comment: Do you have enough cable to turn it sideways, i.e., parallel to the trim?

Comment: Carrying the bevel around looks really good but it's a lot of work depending on the number of outlets. worth it?

Comment: @TomG It would be close. Currently kicking myself for overlooking this. At this point I'm going to just make the trim look the best I can.

Comment: @Steven I only have to do two. :)

Comment: why not turn the outlet sideways?

Answer (score 5):

I settled on going through the trouble of carrying the bevel around the outlet. It's not what I would have done if I had the foresight to move and rewire the boxes, but it's the best option with what I have now.

[image: bevel]

It should look better with a coat or two of paint.

Comment: What is the light brown color that appears on the molding around the outlet box?

Comment: I agree that this mitered approach looks great even though it is clearly a batch of work.

Comment: @MichaelKaras that is the wood filler I used. It will be painted over.